# require is not defined (react.production.min.js) on production build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, production

Good day! I have some troubles to build on production: require is not defined. It caused by react.production.min.js.
Here is my webpack.config.js && package.json

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

let plugins = [
  new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Promise: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.Promise!core-js/es6/promise',
    fetch: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!fetch-polyfill'
  }),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env':{
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      'BASE_URL':JSON.stringify(process.env.BASE_URL)
    }
  })
];

if(!debug) {
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      unsafe_comps: true,
      properties: true,
      keep_fargs: false,
      pure_getters: true,
      collapse_vars: true,
      unsafe: true,
      warnings: false,
      screw_ie8: true,
      sequences: true,
      dead_code: true,
      drop_debugger: true,
      comparisons: true,
      conditionals: true,
      evaluate: true,
      booleans: true,
      loops: true,
      unused: true,
      hoist_funs: true,
      if_return: true,
      join_vars: true,
      cascade: true,
      drop_console: true
    },
    sourceMap: false
  }));
}

module.exports = {
  cache:debug,
  devtool:debug ? "cheap-module-eval-source-map" : "",
  context:path.join(__dirname,'/src'),
  entry:{
    index:'./index.js'
  },
  output:{
    path:path.join(__dirname,'build'),
    filename:'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename:'js/bundles/[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    publicPath:'/build/'
  },
  resolve:{
    modules:["node_modules"],
    extensions:['.js','.jsx','.css','.scss']
  },
  resolveLoader:{
    modules:["node_modules"],
    moduleExtensions:['*-loader',"*"]
  },
  module:{
    noParse:[/\.min\.js$|\.production\.min\.js$/],
    rules:[{
      test:/\.(sass|scss)$/,
      use:[
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader:'css-loader',
          options:{
            modules:true,
            localIdentName: '[local]'
          }
        },
        'sass-loader?resolve url'
      ]
    },{
      test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
      include:[path.join(__dirname,'/src')],
      exclude:[path.join(__dirname,'/build')],
      use:[{
        loader:"babel-loader",
        options:{
          presets:['es2015','react','babel-polyfill','stage-0'],
          plugins:[
            // [
            //   "module-alias",[
            //     {"src":"./styles","expose":"@app-styles"},
            //     {"src":"./api","expose":"@app-api"},
            //     {"src":"./utils","expose":"@app-utils"},
            //     {"src":"./constants","expose":"@app-constants"},
            //     {"src":"./decorate","expose":"@app-decorate"},
            //     {"src":"./stores","expose":"@app-stores"},
            //     {"src":"./services","expose":"@app-services"},
            //     {"src":"./components","expose":"@app-components"},
            //     {"src":"./utils/invariant.js","expose":"@invariant"}
            //   ]
            // ],
            'syntax-async-functions',
            'syntax-dynamic-import',
            'transform-async-to-generator',
            'transform-regenerator',
            ['transform-runtime',{
              "helpers": false,
              "polyfill": false,
              "regenerator": true
            }],
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            'transform-es3-property-literals'
          ]
        }
      }],
    },{
      test:/\.json$/,
      use:[{
        loader:'json-loader'
      }]
    },{
      test:/\.css$/,
      use:[
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'postcss-loader'
      ]
    },{
      test:/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
      use:['url-loader?limit=100000']
    }]
  },
  plugins:plugins,
  stats: { colors: true }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ippf-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "javascript core",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "SET NODE_ENV=development& webpack --watch --progress",
    "server": "node static-server.js",
    "prestart": "npm run package",
    "package": "SET NODE_ENV=production& webpack -p --progress",
    "package_unix": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress",
    "test:single": "karma start karma.conf.js --log-level debug --single-run",
    "test:watch": "karma start karma.conf.js --auto-watch --log-level debug",
    "stats": "webpack --profile --json > stats.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "fetch-polyfill": "^0.8.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-intl": "^1.2.2",
    "react-draggable": "3.0.3",
    "mobx-react": "^4.2.2",
    "mobx": "^3.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.0",
    "i18next": "10.0.7",
    "react-grid-layout": "0.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-alias": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "2.7.1",
    "babel-plugin-object-assign": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.20.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-edge-launcher": "^0.4.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.9.1"
  },
  "author": "_",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

All is good on dev, but when I use "npm run package", it will cause this problem. Please, help! Thanks
Best regards, Petr

Comment: Why do you use `react.production.min.js` if you use Webpack ?

Comment: @dev-null 
to minimize build's time, btw it shouldnt matter, cuz it worked before v16.0 react

Answer (score 7):

production builds won't work if babel doesn't process `react.production.min.js`. This line in your webpack config `noParse:[/\.min\.js$|\.production\.min\.js$/]` will prevent that from happening. Remove that line then your production builds should be good.